# Mark dates on Tapku calendar months as per JSON response

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, tapku

I have JSON response that gives me different dates when events are scheduled in a month.
I am using Tapku calendar in iOS app.

I have following questions:

1. How to mark dates in Tapku calendar which has events scheduled for them. I have seen random  dates generated between two dates to mark events, but I want my own dates received from Json response.
2. On prev and next month clicks, how to get JSon data and mark dates on Tapku calendar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ Mobility: Have you found solution  for your question? If so, upload the solution. I am also having the same requirement in my app.

Comment: @iOS:I am also having the same issue, please post the solution if any of you have now.

Answer (score 2):

i am not sure but may be you can mark dates from this delegate `calendarMonthView` like bellow:-

```
-(NSArray *)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView marksFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)lastDate
{
    // adds marks to the individual dates
    // return an array containing boolean values (YES/NO)
    // whether to mark the date[index];
}
```

Comment: I did this. This code will work.    - (NSArray*) calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView*)monthView marksFromDate:(NSDate*)startDate toDate:(NSDate*)lastDate{
       NSMutableArray *marks = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2012-12-01 00:00:00 +0000",@"2012-11-01 00:00:00 +0000", nil];
   .....
 
}

 Refer http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers#the-code